# intent.getStringExtra не работает

Tags: java, android

Не могу получить данные через интент. Вот так я вызываю интент :

```
case R.id.edit:
    Intent gonder = new Intent(this,EditPasses.class);
    gonder.putExtra("id",info.id);
    startActivity(gonder);
```

И так получаю данные:

```
atext = intent.getStringExtra("id");
password.setText(atext);
```

Результат пустой. Вообще ничего не выводится. Не знаю что делать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После того как задал вопрос решил смотреть на лог Стектрейса. И там нашел вот это:

> Key id expected String but value was a java.lang.Long.  The default
>   value  was returned

Для ключа `id` нужна `String` но отправлено тип `java.lang.Long`. Это и есть причина проблемы.
Изменил

```
Intent gonder = new Intent(this,EditPasses.class);
gonder.putExtra("id",info.id);
startActivity(gonder);
```

на:

```
Intent gonder = new Intent(this,EditPasses.class);
gonder.putExtra("id",""+info.id);
startActivity(gonder);
```

Теперь всё работает.

Answer (score 2):

Вероятно, что `info.id` не `String`. `info.id` я так догадываюсь это `adaperInfo` (не помню как называется точно), а значит:

```
intent.putExtra("id", (int) info.id);
```

В др. активити:

```
position = getIntent().getIntExtra("id", 0);
```

Comment: `info.id` было id выбранного елемента из БД.